# Set 16x16 image as mouse cursor in java

Tags: java

How to set 16x16 image as mouse cursor without scaling that image in java?

Answer (score 2):

Windows cursors must always be 32x32 pixels in size.  If you specify an image smaller than that, Windows will scale the image to 32x32.  This is a problem, because the hotspot you set does not scale.  The solution to this problem is to add transparent pixels to the right and bottom of your cursor image to make the image be 32x32.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
  Image image = toolkit.getImage("icons/your_image.png");
  Cursor c = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image , new Point(mainPanel.getX(),mainPanel.getY()), "img");
  mainPanel.setCursor (c);
```

Comment: This solution is scale 16x16 image.

Comment: Then I guess you can hide the cursor and show a JWindow instead. The JWindow will have only your image in it and it's location will be updated on mouseMoved in a MouseListener().